# rails devise with amazon s3 how to limit usage per user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, amazon-s3

I want to setup a video&image viewing function on my site. My idea is deploy everything video,image to amazon s3. I know I should use devise to setup a user signup feature. But I still have few concern about the security issue and usage charge problems

1.Is devise safe?

2.How can I guarantee only user signed in and can only access the video/images on my amazon-s3 via only my sites while they signed in?

3.This is the most most difficult problem.. Can we keep track of a user's usage? let say I dont want each user in my sites accessing more than 100mb/day contents from s3, anyway to acheive this features??

Thankyou in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Devise is most certainly a framework that will allow you to use best practices to authorize and authenticate users (e.g. by doing things like using very strong encryption methods when storing passwords).  But "safe" is a little subjective -- think of Devise as a very good toolbox that will allow you to easily do things that will make your site safe.

Guaranteeing that users will only access data via your site means that you cannot set the default S3 permissions that make content in S3 buckets readable by all.  I am pretty sure S3 is pretty basic in terms of permissions.  Instead consider a gem like [CarrierWave](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave) that makes it easy to move files around, including streaming file from S3 through your server to the user, thus giving you hooks to authenticate by user.  This is also a hook for measuring number of bits transferred.

If I recall, CarrierWave (or maybe Fog?) gives you a way to query the S3 buckets similarly to how you would in a filessystem, so you can check for size.

Comment: thanks! but I took a look with Carrierwave. I dont think it is able to acheive my #3 feature..

Comment: Did you look at Fog?  It's the gem that does the lower-level stuff CarrierWave depends upon.

Comment: I think basically Carrierwave + fog is dealing something with uploading stuffs to amazon s3, isnt it?  How can it related to the implementation of limiting each user's downloading limit in our application for some existed content in s3?(user doesnt has any rights to upload, just admin can upload.)